# Get the word before particular word in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this string in sql 'PIERCESTOWN WEXFORD EIRE'
I want only 'WEXFORD' , the search should be based on the string 'EIRE'
So far I have tried

```
DECLARE @a varchar(500)
SET @a='MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE'
SELECT charindex('EIRE',@a)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@a,1,charindex('EIRE',@a))
```

But it gives me 'MALTON ROAD WICKLOW E'
Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: So from the `MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE` you want `WICKLOW ` only ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @a varchar(500), @v varchar(500)
SET @a='MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE'
SELECT @v = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@a,1,charindex('EIRE',@a)-1)))
SELECT REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(@v), 
            ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@v)),0)-1,LEN(@v)) ) )
```

Result:

```
DATA                        RESULT
-----------------------------------
MALTON EIRE                 MALTON
MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE    WICKLOW
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was searching very hard to get that. God bless you .Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @a varchar(500), @x varchar(500)
SET @a='MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE'
SELECT @x = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@a,1,charindex('EIRE',@a)))

SELECT REVERSE( LEFT( REVERSE(@x), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@x))-1 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for word which is just before "EIRE"

you have to split sentence using any split function.

try like this,

```
DECLARE @a varchar(500)
SET @a='MALTON ROAD WICKLOW EIRE'
;With CTE as
(select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@a,''))


select c.item from CTE c
inner join cte c1 on c.ItemNumber=c1.ItemNumber-1
where c1.item='EIRE'
```